# How to solve the recurrence T(n) = 4T(sqrt(n)) + sqrt(n)?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, formula, master-theorem

The recursion is

```
T(n) = 4T(sqrt(n)) + sqrt(n)
```

I'm not quite sure if I can use the master theorem to solve this by substituting part of the recursion.

My idea would be to say

```
S(n) = T(2^n) = 4T(2^(n/2)) + 2^(n/2) = 4S(n/2) + 2^(n/2)
```

With the master theorem I would then conclude

```
S(n) = O(2^n) -> T(n) = O(n)
```

But I am not sure whether this kind of substitution is right.

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Uh, no, O(2^n) is not quite the same as O(2^(n/2)).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, the right bound is Θ(√n), since √n ≤ n/100 for n ≥ 10<sup>4</sup>, and the Master Theorem solves T'(n) = 4T'(n/100) + √n as Θ(√n), and T(n) = O(T'(n)). The corresponding lower bound Ω(√n) is obvious.

The part where your argument isn't tight is in writing S(n) = O(2<sup>n</sup>), which is true since 2<sup>n/2</sup> = O(2<sup>n</sup>), but the Master Theorem gives you the better bound S(n) = Θ(2<sup>n/2</sup>). This matters because it's the difference between writing T(n) = S(2<sup>lg(n)</sup>) = Θ(2<sup>lg(n)/2</sup>) = Θ(√n) versus what you wrote: T(n) = S(2<sup>lg(n)</sup>) = O(2<sup>lg(n)</sup>) = O(n).

(Stack Overflow sees plenty of these questions, but they're more fitting on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com).)